# Riflessioni sulla regola: a ogni verbo una proposizione dell'analisi del periodo

Tags: grammar

Esiste la regola o linea guida per cui nell'analisi del periodo si identificano le proposizioni andando a contare quanti sono i verbi in una frase. 
Quindi a ogni verbo corrisponde una proposizione. 
La mia domanda è questa: vale sempre questa regola?

In questo esempio "L’auto parcheggiata poco fa davanti al portone verrà rimossa": 
→ “parcheggiata ecc” può essere una relativa implicita, corrispondente alla forma “la quale è stata parcheggiata ecc ecc”
→ però se penso a "parcheggiata" come a un semplice aggettivo, allora si tratta di una parte della principale.

Che pensate?

Answer (score 2):

Nell'esempio che citi nella domanda succede una cosa interessante: se espliciti la relativa, compaiono un verbo (supponendo che parcheggiata fosse prima aggettivo) e una proposizione, che si bilanciano secondo la regola di cui parli. Se invece consideri il participio come un aggettivo non hai nè proposizione nè verbo.

Penso che questa regola sia abbastanza buona come "linea di massima" da seguire per orientarsi nell'analisi del periodo, ma trovo sia più utile a livello logico (quando pensiamo al significato della frase, e cerchiamo di capirla al di là delle esatte parole che sono usate) che morfologico (quando guardiamo alle parole esatte che compongono la frase): ogni verbo regge una proposizione nella frase, il che più o meno generalmente conferma la regola di cui parli.

Due commenti:

- L'italiano offre molti modi di esprimere una frase omettendo o sottintendendo blocchi logici anche importanti: "L'auto è parcheggiata in strada, la moto in garage" (vedi sopra) elide un verbo. Quindi ci sono frasi in cui la subordinata non è retta da alcun verbo esplicito, ma un ragionamento sul significato della frase porta a concludere che un verbo c'è.
- L'analisi del periodo si presta a considerazioni soggettive (che sono parte della ricchezza della lingua) che talvolta la rendono ambigua: non c'è modo di analizzare la frase "l'auto parcheggiata in cortile verrà rimossa" senza fare una scelta. Però la corrispondenza verbo - proposizione sembra reggere abbastanza bene questa scelta. Un esempio sono i verbi sostantivati, "mi piace correre", se "correre" è verbo, parleremo di una subordinata soggettiva, altrimenti lo si considera sostantivo, ed avremo solo la principale e solo il verbo "piace".

Comment: mi sembra che ci sia qualche confusione tra “proposizione” e “preposizione”: potresti rileggere la tua risposta? (Nella domanda non si parlava di preposizioni.) (“Mentre” è un avverbio.)

Comment: Sì, mi sono confuso. Stavo anche per fare un edit alla mia risposta cambiando preposizione con "particella subordinante" (che sistema il mentre e il pronome relativo nell'esempio nella domanda).

Comment: E potresti correggere la risposta?

Comment: Fatto, non avevo tempo prima

Comment: Mi sono permesso di correggere un “oggettiva” in “soggettiva”.

Answer (score 0):

Diffido sempre dalle regole troppo generali e troppo sintetiche allo stesso tempo. Prendi questo esempio

> L'auto è parcheggiata in strada, la moto in garage

La seconda frase potrebbe essere un esempio di ellittica del predicato (non ne sono certo). La mia risposta alla tua domanda è: IMHO no.